# XSLT move element inside another based on ID

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have the following xml:

```
<Metro>
<MeasurementList>
    <Measurement>
        <MeasurementX>
            <Prop1>bla<Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1212</AcqSettingsRef>
            <SensSettingsRef>#33</SensSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementX>
        <MeasurementY>
            <Prop1>bla<Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1213</AcqSettingsRef>
            <SensSettingsRef>#34</SensSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementY>
    </Measurement>
    <Measurement>
        <MeasurementX>
            <Prop1>bla<Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1212</AcqSettingsRef>
            <SensSettingsRef>#33</SensSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementX>
        <MeasurementY>
            <Prop1>bla<Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1214</AcqSettingsRef>
            <SensSettingsRef>#35</SensSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementY>
    </Measurement>
    <Measurement>
        <MeasurementX>
            <Prop1>bla<Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1215</AcqSettingsRef>
            <SensSettingsRef>#36</SensSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementX>
        <MeasurementY>
            <Prop1>bla<Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1216</AcqSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementY>
    </Measurement>
</MeasurementList>
<References>
    <AcqSettings>
        <Id>1212</Id>
        <Prop2>bla<Prop2>
    </AcqSettings>
    <AcqSettings>
        <Id>1213</Id>
        <Prop2>bla<Prop2>
    </AcqSettings>
    <AcqSettings>
        <Id>1214</Id>
        <Prop2>bla<Prop2>
    </AcqSettings>
    <AcqSettings>
        <Id>1215</Id>
        <Prop2>bla<Prop2>
    </AcqSettings>
    <AcqSettings>
        <Id>1216</Id>
        <Prop2>bla<Prop2>
    </AcqSettings>
    <SensSettings>
        <Id>33</Id>
        <Prop3>bla33<Prop3>
    </SensSettings>
    <SensSettings>
        <Id>34</Id>
        <Prop3>bla34<Prop3>
    </SensSettings>
    <SensSettings>
        <Id>35</Id>
        <Prop3>bla35<Prop3>
    </SensSettings>
    <SensSettings>
        <Id>36</Id>
        <Prop3>bla36<Prop3>
    </SensSettings>
</References>
```

And I have to move the 'SensSettings' from it's own element inside the 'AcqSettings' based on the ID relation that 'MeasurementX or MeasurementY' has. The SensSettings might be missing for some.

The result xml should look like this:

```
<Metro>
<MeasurementList>
    <Measurement>
        <MeasurementX>
            <Prop1>bla<Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1212</AcqSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementX>
        <MeasurementY>
            <Prop1>bla<Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1213</AcqSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementY>
    </Measurement>
    <Measurement>
        <MeasurementX>
            <Prop1>bla<Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1212</AcqSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementX>
        <MeasurementY>
            <Prop1>bla<Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1214</AcqSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementY>
    </Measurement>
    <Measurement>
        <MeasurementX>
            <Prop1>bla<Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1215</AcqSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementX>
        <MeasurementY>
            <Prop1>bla<Prop1>
            <AcqSettingsRef>#1216</AcqSettingsRef>
        </MeasurementY>
    </Measurement>
</MeasurementList>
<References>
    <AcqSettings>
        <Id>1212</Id>
        <Prop2>bla<Prop2>
        <Prop3>bla33<Prop3>
    </AcqSettings>
    <AcqSettings>
        <Id>1213</Id>
        <Prop2>bla<Prop2>
        <Prop3>bla34<Prop3>
    </AcqSettings>
    <AcqSettings>
        <Id>1214</Id>
        <Prop2>bla<Prop2>
        <Prop3>bla35<Prop3>
    </AcqSettings>
    <AcqSettings>
        <Id>1215</Id>
        <Prop2>bla<Prop2>
        <Prop3>bla36<Prop3>
    </AcqSettings>
    <AcqSettings>
        <Id>1216</Id>
        <Prop2>bla<Prop2>
    </AcqSettings>
</References>
```

This should be done with a XSLT transform. For now I am not sure how to link the SensSettings to the AcqSettings based on the ID in the measurement.

Comment: In general to follow cross-references you can use `xsl:key` and the `key` function or, as you have also tagged the question as `xsd`, if you use schema-aware XSLT 2 or 3, you can exploit `xs:ID`/`xs:IDREF` declaration in the schema. For your concrete sample, please make sure you present well-formed XML, I am afraid in your current sample there are lots of elements that are not properly closed, like `<Prop2>bla<Prop2>`

Comment: Yes, I made this sample xml quickly and forgot to close some tags. can't use the schema-aware I am afraid. will try with the xsl:key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two keys you can follow the reference and copy the referenced element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:key name="mes-ref" match="MeasurementX | MeasurementY" use="substring(AcqSettingsRef, 2)"/>
  <xsl:key name="setting" match="SensSettings" use="Id"/>

  <xsl:template match="AcqSettings">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="key('setting', key('mes-ref', Id)/SensSettingsRef/substring(., 2))/Prop3"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SensSettings"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2Cg, use XSLT 3 but the use of `xsl:mode` could be replaced in XSLT 2 by spelling out the identity transformation.

Comment: This is a great fix, but this implies the usage of version 2 or 3... is there anything I can do in version 1?

Comment: If `key('mes-ref', Id)/SensSettingsRef` will always only find one element (depends on your sample data) it should suffice to use `<xsl:copy-of select="key('setting', substring(key('mes-ref', Id)/SensSettingsRef, 2))/Prop3"/>` and that is hopefully XSLT/XPath 1 compatible. If the first expression can return more than one element then I think you need `<xsl:for-each select="key('mes-ref', Id)/SensSettingsRef"><xsl:copy-of select="key('setting', substring(., 2))/Prop3"/></xsl:for-each>` and it should do the same job in XSLT 1.